# How to build multi workspace cargo project in rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have multi-workspace Cargo project. It has two workspaces, `common` and `server`. `common` is a `lib` project and server is a `bin` project.

The location of the project in Github is [here.](https://github.com/rajcspsg/multi_module_cargo_project)

Below is the project structure.

```
.
├── Cargo.toml
├── common
│   ├── Cargo.toml
│   └── src
│       └── lib.rs
├── README.md
└── server
    ├── Cargo.toml
    └── src
        └── main.rs

4 directories, 6 files
```

And the file contents of ./Cargo.toml file is

```
[package]
name = "multi_module_cargo_project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["rajkumar"]

[workspace]
members = ["common", "server"]

[dependencies]
```

When I run the command `cargo build --all`:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/home/rajkumar/Coding/Rust/ProgrammingRust/multi_module_cargo_project/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
no targets specified in the manifest
either src/lib.rs, src/main.rs, a [lib] section, or [[bin]] section must be present
```

So I added below in `Cargo.toml` but still couldn't build the project.

```
[[bin]]
name = "server/src/main.rs"
```

How can I build the project. What I'm missing?

Comment: I think you should only put `[workspace]` inside the root manifest and so remove `[package]` and `[dependencies]`, put that only in the manifest inside `server` and `common`.

Comment: @Stargateur - You are right. That works. I would've accepted your answer if you answered the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You included a `[package]` section in your main `Cargo.toml` file.  This section indicates that you want to build a main package in addition to the packages in the workspace.  However, you don't have any source files for the main package, so Cargo complains.

The solution is to simply omit the `[package]` section, and only include `[workspace]`.  This configures a *virtual workspace* – a workspace that is only a container for member packages, but does not build a package itself.

See the [main `Cargo.toml` file of Rocket](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/master/Cargo.toml) for a real-world example of a virtual workspace, and [Tokio](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tokio/blob/master/Cargo.toml) for a real-world example of a workspace with a main package.